# Retrying URL: Connection reset by peer during fetch

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm having trouble with one of the domains my Google Search Appliance (version 7.2) is crawling.

The retrieval error I'm getting is:

> Retrying URL: Connection reset by peer during fetch

Can anyone tell me what can cause such an error or have suggestions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the URL is accessible to GSA. There might not be network connectivity from GSA to the site. You can use "Manual Fetch Request" under Content Sources > Diagnostics > Real-time Diagnostics, or Administration > Network Settings (at a lower level) in the admin console to debug connectivity issues. Ideally in manual fetch request you should get 200 OK when you access the URL.

Comment: Test it repeatedly using Real Time Diagnostics. You may have an intermittent/load issue. Try reducing the host load schedule for that particular server and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome dev, you can do the following things to have a try. The things I also meet today, but I had solved just now.
You can input `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` to the chrome search box. Then you will see a webpage.

> Input a domain name to add it to the HSTS sit:

the line of Domain:[ ],you can input `www.google.com.hk`
this is the way to let chrome visit www.google.com.hk by https  forcibly
I hope it can help you